# How to display searched result in Tableviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I Want to display searched core data results in tableviewcontroller. I know how to display core data in tableview but I want specific data to be displayed in tableviewcontroller.

Like, when user selects a specific city from uipickerview, then results from core data are displayed in tableviewcontroller according to the specific city.

Some codes are listed below.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MenuhospitalTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    private var hospitalcoredata: [Hospitalcoredata] = []
    var fetchResultController:NSFetchedResultsController!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
         Load menu items from database
        if let managedObjectContextt = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContextt {
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Hospitalcoredata")
            var e: NSError?
            hospitalcoredata = managedObjectContextt.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &e) as! [Hospitalcoredata]
            if e != nil {
                println("Failed to retrieve record: \(e!.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
      
        
        // Make the cell self size
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 66.0
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }
    
    
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return hospitalcoredata.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MenuhospitalTableViewCell
        
        // Configure the cell...
        cell.nameLabel.text = hospitalcoredata[indexPath.row].namee
        cell.contactnoLabel.text = hospitalcoredata[indexPath.row].contactnoo
        //        cell.priceLabel.text = "$\(menuItems[indexPath.row].price as! Double)"
        
        return cell
    }
    
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation
    
    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */}
```

and code to find data from city are given below..

```
    let entityDescription =
    NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Register",
        inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    
    let request = NSFetchRequest()
    request.entity = entityDescription
    
    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "(name = %@)", name.text)
    request.predicate = pred
    
    var error: NSError?
    
    var objects = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(request,
        error: &error)
    
    if let results = objects {
        
        if results.count > 0 {
            let match = results[0] as! NSManagedObject
            
            name.text = match.valueForKey("name") as! String
            contactno.text = match.valueForKey("contactno") as! String
            altno.text = match.valueForKey("altno") as! String
            emailid.text = match.valueForKey("emailid") as! String
            textf.text = match.valueForKey("bloodgroup") as! String
            textff.text = match.valueForKey("city") as! String
            
            status.text = "Matches found: \(results.count)"
        } else {
            status.text = "No Match"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to mix up these two codes and display core data results according to "city" selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of try and help of my project guide(prof. chirag pandya),

Answer:

use preparesegue method in first view controller,
give name of push segue,
use segue name, 
create predicate in second view controller and use first viewcontroller.
vary useful for searching and sorting

Code:
1)IN (firstviewcontroller)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier=="segueTest"){
        var svc = segue.destinationViewController as! MenuhospitalTableViewController
        svc.toPass = textff.text
    }
}
```

2)IN (secondviewcontroller)

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "(city = %@)", toPass)
        fetchRequest.predicate = pred
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate your table view. Add a dynamic predicate to its fetch request and `performFetch` before you update your table view.

Comment: i try your method but error occured because i want to search result from Hospital view controller and code for fetch and sort is added to another view controller.  can i use first text field to next view controller ? how it is possible..   Thanks for reply @Mundi

Comment: Sure. Just pass pass the string from the text field to the next view controller and use it to construct the predicate.